# fatal error: zend_smart_str.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, php7

I am trying to install oci8 using "pecl install oci8" command but getting error as -

```
fatal error: zend_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zend_smart_str.h"
```

following are my system details - 
1.ubuntu 14.04
2.php 7.0.17-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

**steps I followed -**

1. download instantclient-basic-linux-12.2.0.1.0.zip
2. download instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
3. create dir in /opt/oracle
4. extract both zip files
5. run **pecl install oci8** command

**Outout -**

```
/bin/bash /tmp/oci8-2.1.4/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4/include -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4/main -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/oci8-2.1.4/oci8.c -o oci8.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4/include -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4/main -I/tmp/oci8-2.1.4 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/oci8-2.1.4/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
/tmp/oci8-2.1.4/oci8.c:36:28: fatal error: zend_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zend_smart_str.h"
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [oci8.lo] Error 1
```

Please help!! Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. php 7.0.17-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev`

Provides `/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_smart_str.h`

Comment: okay let me check it and will update. Thank you!!

Comment: sorry it didn't work, however I have resolved it by downloading lower version - instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.1.0.zip and instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.1.0.zip. 
Thanks much for your reply.